# Newly created graphics object only showing after resize of frame

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

This is a continuation from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479132/trying-to-add-a-dynamically-positioned-image-in-a-jpanel-on-a-button-click/7557846#7557846)

I have a set of random sized graphics adding and drawing onto a JPanel component. I have a button that is adding a new draw object to the same JPanel but is not displaying until i re-size the window. I have added the EDT information mentioned in [this post](http://netzwerg.ch/?p=137) and have also called the repaint() method on the component.  I am not using an ArrayList yet, as suggested by [Hovercraft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels), but I will.  My brain needs to understand things slowly as i go.

Thank you.

The code is in two classes.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ZombieDance extends JComponent {

JFrame canvas = new JFrame();
JPanel actionPanel = new JPanel();
JButton newZombie = new JButton("Add new Zombie");

ZombieDance(){
//create a couple default zombies
    buildGUI();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i,x,y,w,h;

    //add zombies to my canvas
    for (i=1;i<8;i++) {
        float r = rand.nextFloat();
        float g = rand.nextFloat();
        float b = rand.nextFloat();
        x = rand.nextInt(50);
        y = rand.nextInt(50);
        w = rand.nextInt(50);
        h = rand.nextInt(50); 
        canvas.add(new Zombie(x,y,w,h,r,g,b));
    }   
}

//prep the canvas
void buildGUI(){
    actionPanel.add(newZombie);
    canvas.add(actionPanel);
    canvas.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    canvas.setSize(400,400);
    canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.setVisible(true);

    newZombie.addActionListener(new NewZombieClickHandler());
}

public class NewZombieClickHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int x,y,w,h;
        float r = rand.nextFloat();
        float g = rand.nextFloat();
        float b = rand.nextFloat();
        x = rand.nextInt(50);
        y = rand.nextInt(50);
        w = rand.nextInt(50);
        h = rand.nextInt(50); 
        canvas.add(new Zombie(x,y,w,h,r,g,b));
        canvas.repaint();
    }
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          new ZombieDance();
        }
    });
  }
```

}

Second class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Zombie extends JPanel{

private int x,y,w,h;
private float r,g,b;

Zombie(int argx, int argy, int argw, int argh, float argr, float argg, float argb){
    x = argx;
    y = argy;
    w = argw;
    h = argh;
    r = argr;
    g = argg;
    b = argb;
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(20,20);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);       
    //g.drawString("Drawing canvas...",10,20);
    gr.setColor(new Color(r,g,b));
    gr.fillRect(x,y,h,w);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a button that is adding a new draw object to the same JPanel but is not displaying until i re-size the window

When you add a component to a visible GUI the code should be:

```
canvas.add(...);
canvas.validate();
//canvas.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

(editor: changed to *validate*)

Comment: revalidate() was invalid for me, but validate() solved the problem. I am using JVM 1.6. Thank you for quick simple response.

Comment: @jamesTheProgrammer: Try `((JPanel)canvas.getContentPane()).revalidate();`

Comment: @Hovercaft, your code worked too.  Difference? Best practice?

Comment: @jamesTheProgrammer, the validate() method was used for AWT components. The revalidate() method was added for Swing components (ie. components that extend from JComponent). I prefer to use the method that was designed for Swing. Normally you add components to a JPanel directly so you have access to the panel and you just revalidate() it.

Answer (score -1):

I tried myself and i found that paintChildren() method resolved the problem.